# Dynamic swap file with systemd swap unit

Tags: debian, systemd, swap

On each boot a temporary partition is mounted at `/mnt/tmp`. The temporary partition varies in size.

I need to set a swapfile on it which is half the size of the partition.

Is this possible with systemd swap unit?

I think I can do this with a systemd service unit incorporating a dedicated script that makes the swap file and activates it, and that depends on the temporary partition being mounted. But a swap unit doesn't have this functionality of executing scripts, hence I wonder whether I am on the right track?